# Return exact match when using Maven GAVC artifact search Artifactory REST API

Tags: maven, artifactory

Is there a way to find Maven artifact in Artifactory and get exact match (by name) when searching using artifact's name?

Using [GAVC search API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GAVCSearch) produces results prefixed by artifact name (`artifact` in the below example):

```
GET /api/search/gavc?g=org.acme&a=artifact&v=1.0&c=sources&repos=libs-release-local
{
"results": [
    {
        "uri": "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/storage/libs-release-local/org/acme/artifact/1.0/artifact-1.0-sources.jar"
    },{
        "uri": "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/storage/libs-release-local/org/acme/artifactB/1.0/artifactB-1.0-sources.jar"
    }
]
}
```

Current workaround is filtering API response results in code.

Comment: Can you please describe more in detail what you exact problem is because I don't understand your question in particular `get exact match when searching using artifact's name?`?

Comment: you can see the problem in the example. searching by artifact name using Artifactory REST API returns 2 results: one is exact match, one is not

Comment: The search is not an exact search. The given artifactId is not the 100% requirement... but that's a problem of Artifactory... I would ask Jfrog people... to make a search which uses exact matches which is not the case...

Comment: Usually, I use AQL queries. You cannot search for GAVs AFAIK, but you can convert the GAV to a path and then search for it.